# How to add virtualenv to path

Tags: python, macos, path, virtualenv, pip

I am trying to find out why my `virtualenv` and/or `virtualenv` wrapper - installed using `pip` using `homebrew` - cannot be found. I think it's because it's not added to my PATH:

```
$ which virtualenv
$
```

and:

```
$ virtualenv someDir
$ -bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

I installed pip using `homebrew`, and `virtualenv` using `pip`, without problems. I tried reinstalling `virtualenv`, but that did not work either.
How do I know what path to add to `PATH`? Just the path that `virtualenv.py` seems to be installed into? That seems to be:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py
```

I also found [this guide](http://youshoulddoityourself.blogspot.nl/2010/11/test.html), which suggests this:

```
$ ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv virtualenv
```

However, it does not help me run `virtualenv`. I am on Mac OSX 10.7.5 (Lion).

Comment: It's not a path issue. Pip puts an executable file named `virtualenv` in `/usr/local/bin/` when successfully installed. Try `pip uninstall virtualenv` and then reinstall `sudo pip install virtualenv`. `sudo` because you'll need to install it in global scope.

Comment: @Bibhas but if i load launchd.conf, i have /usr/local/bin added to my path so then i should be able to just use virtualenv in bash right? or pip only put it there when using sudo? where could i have found this information?

Comment: @Bibhas i tried what you suggested, i did:
    + $ pip uninstall virtualenv
    + $ pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
    + $ sudo pip install virtualenv
    + $ cd /usr/local/bin/ 
    + $ find virtualenv
    + find: virtualenv: No such file or directory``

So something is going wrong here? that would make sense... but why??

Comment: how did you install pip? which package did you install with brew? can you check the pip version with `pip -V`? when you install virtualenv with pip, does it give any error? can you post the install log?

Comment: See this screenshot http://d.pr/i/paQQ for the first 3 questions, and this one for installing virtualenv: http://d.pr/i/c4pE and virtualenvwrapper: http://d.pr/i/L7E0 Also, i had no errors installing virtualenv at any time, i did have warnings..

Comment: my solution was :   sudo -H pip install virtualenv

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that I myself am the exception to the rule for almost all 'simple' installation procedures. For some reason, it WAS a path related issue:

I ran `brew info python`, which outputted a lot of information. At the bottom I found this:

```
Executable python scripts will be put in:
/usr/local/share/python
so you may want to put "/usr/local/share/python" in your PATH, too.
```

I added that to my PATH in `/etc/launchd.conf` and `~/.bashrc` and lo and behold:

```
$ which virtualenv
```

tells me:

```
"/usr/local/share/python/virtualenv"
```

I still don't know why I couldn't find any pointers in the right direction, online, anywhere? Is `pip install virtualenv` supposed to add to the PATH itself? If so, why not on my system? Why did @bibhas tell me explicitly it was not a path issue?

Comment: funny cause brew just told me to remove that from my path because it works differently now, yet then i could no longer use virtualenv..

Comment: Thanks for a well-written solution, totally solved my problem.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue after `pip install virtualenv`

When I inspected python `ls -la /usr/local/bin/python` I found it was symbolically linked to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

When I cd in that directory I also found the virtualenv executable and

Fixed it by

1. `cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`
2. `ln virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

Sidenote: I also happen to have a python installation in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`

I believe that's the one that came with OSX

Comment: Worked for me.  I'm curious what caused it to end up in this state.

Comment: Worked for me, although my virtualenv executable was at a different location. Also turns out the pip install virtualenv, outcome, has a waring message indicating that /usr/local/bin/virtualenv should be added to PATH.

Comment: Works! Similar to Kevin, my executable was in a slightly different location, but still within python's folder in user's library.

Answer (score 2):

In your .bashrc you need to have:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: When i try this (i've put it in both .bashrc which i had to create, and .bash_profile) it tells me this:
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: and then open a new bash shell: `bash` or close and reopen your terminal

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by:
At first, I found out it is located at `/usr/local/python3`
and then I fixed it by the command:

```sh
ln virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Answer (score 1):

(Mac / Linux specific)
So I got an error message when I did a `pip3 install --user --upgrade virtualenv` telling me that I did not have `Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/bin` in my PATH. So I simply added it.

If this is on the Mac, the following did it for me

```
vi ~/.bash_profile



PATH="/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
```

restart your terminal and type `virtualenv env` and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will give you an alternate tool to use and solve your `virtualenv` problem at the same time.

Use [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew). It is inspired from `rvm` in the ruby world and is helpful in managing pythons on your system and also wrap `virtualenv` commands to provide virtual environment management. I use it Mountain Lion for my development purposes and have had no problems. More details (on my blog): http://stacktoheap.com/blog/2013/03/11/why-use-virtualenv-when-there-is-pythonbrew/

Comment: I think this is nice if it works out of the box, but 1) it's a workaround for my problem, and 2) i cannot install it using homebrew, which i came to like as a package manager since a few months :)

Comment: this i could have expected: if i download pythonbrewm which relies on virtualenv, and i try to use it, guess what:
**``futuremaggel:~ supermaggel$ pythonbrew
-bash: pythonbrew: command not found
futuremaggel:~ supermaggel$ which pythonbrew
futuremaggel:~ supermaggel$``**
it doesn't know the command or cannot find it.. same problem as i have with virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to add your virtualenv position to the BASH PATH

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/python2.7/bin`
Or change your position

Answer (score 0):

For those with Python 2.7, I came across this as well, and solved it by simply putting the following line into the `\etc\paths` file (may need to `$ sudo chmod` it first):

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
```

Save the change and start a new Terminal session. Check it with `echo $PATH`

Answer (score -1):

The module in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is imported by a short script that uses `pkg_resources.load_entry_point` to run the application.  The utility script should be in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: i'm sorry, but my pip/bash fu is not nearly good enough to understand your solution, could you please elaborate?