# Error "virtualenv : command not found" but install location is in PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

This has been driving me crazy for the past 2 days.
I installed virtualenv on my Macbook using `pip install virtualenv`.
But when I try to create a new virtualenv using `virtualenv venv`, I get the error saying "virtualenv : command not found".

I used `pip show virtualenv` and the location of the installation is "Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" but I can't figure out where the executable is. I tried dozens other similar looking posts but those solutions do not work for me.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure your python path is correct? Are you using the system installed python, or one you downloaded on your own?

Comment: Pythonpath wouldn't affect executing a program from the commandline...

Comment: Can you try `python -m venv`?

Comment: @cricket_007 : I've been using it for the past 2 years so I'm not sure but I think its the default installation. When I do `which python`, I get "/usr/local/bin/python"

Comment: @Gator_Python: Yes when I do "python -m virtualenv venv" it creates the virtual environment. Thanks. But I wonder why this is not the default method to use virtualenv and still don't understand why the method listed in the docs doesn't work for me.

Comment: `/usr/local` means you've downloaded your own python, which is separate from `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/`. If `virtualenv` cannot be found, then you are missing `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

Comment: @cricket_007 so what can I do to have an executable in /usr/local/bin/virtualenv ?

Comment: I have python installed via homebrew. When I did `pip install virtualenv`, it created it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add virtualenv to path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453793/how-to-add-virtualenv-to-path)

Comment: re: `pip install virtualenv` , I had to use `sudo` to get that command to succeed.

Comment: mine installed in a strange place

Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages

I used sudo pip3 install -U virtualenv  # system-wide install

Anybody know why I get virtualenv : command not found?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The only workable approach I could figure out (with help from @Gator_Python was to do `python -m virtualenv venv`. This creates the virtual environment and works as expected.

I have custom python installed and maybe that's why the default approach doesn't work for me.

Comment: Works with the official Python3 download on El Capitan. Thanks.

Comment: This was roughly where I landed as well.  Ultimately ended up adding an alias to my `.bashrc` so that I could save myself some typing.

Comment: More detailed version of this same Answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39977369/1357094

Comment: I did python3 -m virtualenv venv 

so python3 instead of python because I have both installed, might be useful for other noobs...

Comment: I also installed python with custom path, maybe that cause cannot find virtualenv with default approach.

Answer (score 20):

On macOS Mojave
First check python is in the path.
`python --version`
Second check pip is installed.
`pip --version`
If it is not installed.
`brew install pip`
Third install virtualenv
`sudo -H pip install virtualenv`

Answer (score 18):

For Python 3

```
python3 -m virtualenv venv
```

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comments, you've got the virtualenv module installed properly in the expected environment since `python -m venv` allows you to create virtualenv's.

The fact that `virtualenv` is not a recognized command is a result of the `virtualenv.py` not being in your system PATH and/or not being executable. The root cause could be outdated distutils or setuptools.

You should attempt to locate the `virtualenv.py` file, ensure it is executable (`chmod +x`) and that its location is in your system PATH. On my system, `virtualenv.py` is in the `../Pythonx.x/Scripts` folder, but this may be different for you.

Comment: The first solution worked for me, but the second failed, despite locating `virtualenv` in `~/lib/python/site-packages`, adding this directory to the `PATH`, and making `virtualenv.py` executable. I am on macOS Mojave with Python 3.6.7 and pip3.

Comment: On macOS Mojave you can do `sudo -H pip install virtualenv`

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are using Anaconda package manager?  If so, then it has it's own virtual environment system which you setup as follows:

```
conda create --name venv
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (although on ubuntu), a simple solution is instead of doing `pip install virtualenv`, you precede the commend with "**sudo**".

A little inspection reveals the reason behind this fix:
[image]

`pip install virtualenv` tries to put an executable under `/usr/local/bin` so that it can be invoked from command line, but it failed because only root has write permission to that directory

an alternative is `pip install --user virtualenv`, here are some further readings [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310688/sudo-pip-install-vs-pip-install-user),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on Windows. Command not found and can't find the executable in the directory given by pip show.

Fixed it by adding "C:\Users{My User}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts" to the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Install virtualenv from https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv

> python -m pip install --user virtualenv

```
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeded creating manually a link to *location*/virtualenv.py in /usr/local/bin, naming it virtualenv and adding +x attribute on file

```
➜  ~ pip show virtualenv
Name: virtualenv
Version: 16.6.0
Summary: Virtual Python Environment builder
Home-page: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/
Author: Ian Bicking
Author-email: ianb@colorstudy.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/prsadev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: 


~ chmod +x /home/prsadev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py 
~ sudo ln -sf /home/prsadev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to have virtualenv at a random location & faced the same issue on a UBUNTU machine, when I tried to run my 'venv'. What solved my issue was :-

*$`virtualenv -p python3 venv`*

Also,instead of using $`activate` try :-
*$`source activate`*
If you look at the activate script(or $`cat activate`), you will find the same in comment.

Answer (score 0):

**This solved my similar problem!**

You need to look online on `how to create a virtual environement with python X.X.X` (replace x.x.x with your python version)

mine was python 3.4.3 so bellow is how should i deal with it:

```
sudo python3 -m venv aramisvenv
```

Answer (score 0):

I use asdf and had to do a reshim after installing virtualenv. `asdf reshim`

Fixed due to this [response](https://github.com/danhper/asdf-python/issues/51#issuecomment-472556956)