# virtualenv env bash: virtualenv: command not found

Tags: python, django, virtual-machine, virtualenv

I have a problem each time I want to start my VM even after Installing on windows
`

```
$ pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-20.16.6-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<3,>=2.4 in c:\users\samib\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.6 in c:\users\samib\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.4.1 in c:\users\samib\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.8.0)
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\samib\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed virtualenv-20.16.6
```

`
I have the error

```
virtualenv env bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

I tried to uninstall and install again but I have the same issue

Comment: does `python -m virtualenv` work?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964635/error-virtualenv-command-not-found-but-install-location-is-in-pythonpath